# Adding legend to plot when using append

Tags: plotting, legending

I am making a plot using

```
 f[m_, i_] := i + Sqrt[m];

  LazyDriftPlot = Plot[
  Evaluate@Append[Table[f[m, i], {i, 0, 40, 10}], f[m, 5.5]], {m, 1, 
   100},
  PlotLabel -> "Average lazy drift",
  PlotLegends -> Append[Table[i, {i, 0, 40, 10}], 5.5],
  AxesLabel -> {
    Style[m, FontSize -> 18], Style[d[m], FontSize -> 18]
    }
  ]
```

How can I add a label to the legend here?

I've tried

```
PlotLegends -> {Append[...],LegendLabel->"MyLabel"}
```

but it is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

SwatchLegend comes to the rescue!

```
LazyDriftPlot = 
 Plot[Evaluate@Append[Table[f[m, i], {i, 0, 40, 10}], f[m, 5.5]], {m, 
   1, 100}, PlotLabel -> "Average lazy drift", 
  PlotLegends -> 
   SwatchLegend[Append[Table[i, {i, 0, 40, 10}], 5.5], 
    LegendMarkers -> "Line", LegendLabel -> "MyLabel"], 
  AxesLabel -> {Style[m, FontSize -> 18], 
    Style[d[m], FontSize -> 18]}]
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thank you, SwatchLegend!